# Can I use JPA to populate fields with generated data (ie using a View)?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, view, insert

I've actually gotten this to work, partially, using a View, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

I have a database table, ESCROW, that maps to a entity.  I then created a view, called ESCROW_DERIVED, which contains the same columns as the table, but also has another column defined as:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM escrow_access a WHERE e.id=a.escrow AND a.viewed=1) 
    as num_dirty
```

I modified my entity to point to the view, and added the following attribute:

```
@Column(name = "NUM_DIRTY")
private Integer numDirty;
```

Retrieving the data works great.  The problem is when I try to do an insert.  I get the following error:

**Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here**

I just want my entity to have **numDirty** populated so I can use it for display purposes.  Using something like this View allows me to retrieve the data with a single query.

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: So the Entity is mapped to a VIEW now (not a table)? In which case you can't insert/update/delete data of that type.

Comment: You will need 2 entities. One for view, another one for table. Insert, update and deletes must be done against the table's entity.

Comment: Is there a way to do this elegantly or will I have to manually copy the values of EscrowDerived into Escrow before persisting?  Is there a way to do my reads from the view but writes into the table (using a single entity)?